# How to handle user input data validation with Firebase Firestore Security rules?

Tags: regex, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a Frontend App with Vue backed with Firebase. For data persistence I'm using Firestore which works really fine. However, I just got to the point where I need to validate the data a user sends to Firestore.

Although I'm validating the inputs with client-side (VeeValidate), I know it is important to validate that data in my backend. The way I have found is through Security Rules. I have been developing APIs with Laravel, which has a powerful validation package.

What I would like to implement is something like Laravel's Validation, where I can check if a string is alpha spaces or alpha-dashes only.

I know firebase has some helpers like string.matches(regex) to check for a given regex pattern on a string. But, I'm not sure how should I implement that,since some documents could contain more than 10 fields to validate against several rules (valid email, alpha, alpha_dashes, etc), turning the Security Rules into a growing monster.

So, my actual question is, how should I handle data validation with Firebase Firestore?

Comment: As you've already found out, you'll use security rules to validate data in Firestore on the server. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're asking. Is there a specific rule you're having trouble with?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well actually, the thing is, if I do have a document, let's say a User Profile, which has 10 fields, Name, Lastname, Birthday, etc.. and each field could have one or more patterns to check against, my question is if that is the correct approach, to use matches(regex) on every field for every pattern, or is there another better approach

Comment: What is better is usually highly subjective. But using Firestore's server side security rules to validate the data stored in the database is a valid approach.

Comment: Well yeah. So I think everyone who wants to validate user input has to build validation rules/functions from scratch :/ Not very useful though